# Why was my typo post undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, undeleted-questions

### My [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640818/wait-for-function-doesnt-work-in-pycord/71642375#71642375)

[image]

I originally deleted it because it probably couldn't help others in the future. I know that there was an answer, and it weighs me down on the question ban, but how can it help future users? Isn't it just clutter for the site? Should I redelete it?

Comment: My guess the reason is you are ...posting quite often to meta recently thus making mod to look at all your posts. Possibly they noticed rude behavior of deleting a question with existing answer. Check your inbox if there is a mod's reminder not to do that in the future. (Note that this is pure guess and I have no insights into mod's mind).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It was just one question that probably couldn't help anyone (it even hurts me to keep it). Nothing in my inbox. Just wondering why it was undeleted in the first place.

Comment: “I know that there was an answer, and it weighs me down on the question ban, but how can it help future users?” - Regardless if it’s deleted or stays undeleted, it would count towards or against, your ability to ask additional questions.  **It takes more than one bad question for a question ban.**

Comment: @SecurityHound I think I remember reading that deleted questions weigh heavier than undeleted ones.

Comment: @BlueRobin - So you are better off it not being deleted, if that’s true, nobody know if it’s true or not. It was probably undeleted becoming of the accepted upvoted answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound I guess, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291436/when-deleting-own-question-do-i-lose-reputation-points I found it

Comment: @SecurityHound such rude action as deleting post with an answer may very well push one to the ban based on meta posts around q-ban. (I'd definitely not recommend such action on 0 scored post) .

Comment: @BlueRobin - That answer talks about reputation, it says absolutely nothing, about not counting towards a question ban.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I don’t disagree it’s rude to ask a question, have it receive an answer, then delete it. However, it takes more than one deleted questions with 0 votes before that would happen

Comment: @SecurityHound It does. *You won't suffer a penalty for deletion, but it could (but not often*) count against you for the question ban, but occasional deletion when other posts are of high quality will not result in any negative effect.*

Comment: @BlueRobin - 100% of the users that I have seen ask about their question ban, have more than a handful of deleted questions, they also often have questions with 0 votes. But no doubt 100% of those users have deleted questions, so I have no doubt, deleted questions count against you (or perhaps are unable to count positively towards the ability)

Comment: @SecurityHound That seems to be the case, yes.

Comment: @BlueRobin this is one quite selective reading :) - did you check the exception part "authors who delete their questions immediately upon receiving an answer" (also in the case of the linked question you was not the one deleting the post... so it should not count against you more than any other post... would be far easier if you did that yourself and undeleting by mod would help just by action itself... Now it looks like you actually have chance to fix it up... if possible)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No, I haven't. What post is that on?

Comment: Deleted posts count towards your question ban. Do you not want any help with lifting your question ban? By posting this on Meta you are bringing further unnecessary attention to your question and your question ban may be extended. See what is [The Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: @SamuelLiew you probably should post an answer to clarify your actions. I posted my POV, but I'm really not sure what positive result you expected from un-deletion of *this particular post* (I don't see how on can get upvotes for fixing up typo question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov seems like a pretty okay question to me, much better than the average junk question we get. The question is: how many people are likely to repeat that misinterpretation of documentation? Not many in this case I'm afraid, it is already a pretty niche topic to begin with. That is the only reason I don't expect this question to turn around in votes, it is not the quality of the question itself. A more common example I would say is registering javascript handers for html events, using "onclick" instead of "click" for example. That'll trap a whole lot more people.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I am thankful you did this. I just wanted to know why, as I've never had a question of mine un-deleted before. I assumed it was deleted by myself, but I seem to have forgotten it was deleted by a bot. So, thanks! My curiosity got the best of me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at timelines of Q&A there is nothing particularly bad from Q-ban point of view. Answer was deleted by the answer's vote the day question was asked and later the question was cleaned up by roomba. When un-deleted the question had 0 score likely not impacting q-ban much.

Now my guess why the question was un-deleted: Blue Robin is quite active on meta recently trying to get out of q-ban. So usually, to do that the person needs to edit all their questions including deleted ones, but roomba-deleted posts require mod action to undelete. Presumably mod decided to be proactive and help that way. My initial guess was the question was considered as "deleted by OP immediately after receiving an answer" (which is presumed to be costly for q-ban), but that is not the case as answer was also un-deleted by the same mod - so they knew that question did not have an answer when it was deleted (even if they ignored roomba deletion).

Whether this actually helpful or harmful is open question as it is very unlikely to turn typo to on-topic question... but very likely to start collecting downvotes due to meta effect.

Unfortunately at this point there is not much to be done by OP as they can't delete the question with upvoted answer and editing it in shape is unlikely as typo usually can be self-found by providing MRE.

Comment: Important to highlight that a single question, that perhaps should be deleted but now isn't deleted, by itself has little effect on the author being question ban.  In fact the question is better off with a question with 2 upvotes not being deleted, despite the negative score, since upvotes and downvotes are not weighed the same (presumably).